# Bouncy castle error: Unable to cast object of type RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters to type ElGamalKeyParameters

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption, elgamal

I am having difficulties with decryption of a GPG file using Bouncy Castle. I have the encrypted file and I have a private key and the password for the private key. I can successfully decrypt the file using the desktop software GPG4win Kleopatra so I have the correct private key and the gpg file is valid.

However when our application reaches the line of code which attempts to decrypt the data with Bouncy Castle, I receive this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters' to type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ElGamalKeyParameters'.
```

I am decrypting the same file using the same private key with Kleopatra so this has got to be something I can resolve by perhaps changing the private key file to the expected format or setting some options in Bouncy Castle.

The private key file is a plain text file beginning with the lines:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.17 (MingW32)
```

Here is a flattened out version of the decryption code. Apologies if I have missed anything out:

```
PgpEncryptionKeys encryptionKeys = new PgpEncryptionKeys(publicKey, privateKey, passPhrase);

Stream encryptedStream = new StreamReader(encryptedFileName).BaseStream;
Stream encodedFile = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(inputStream);

PgpObjectFactory factory = new PgpObjectFactory(encodedFile);
PgpObject pgpObject = factory.NextPgpObject();

PgpEncryptedDataList encryptedDataList;
if (pgpObject is PgpEncryptedDataList)
{
    encryptedDataList = (PgpEncryptedDataList)pgpObject;
}
else
{
    encryptedDataList = (PgpEncryptedDataList)factory.NextPgpObject();
}

PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData myEncryptedData = null;
PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData publicKeyED = null;
foreach (PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData encryptedData in encryptedDataList.GetEncryptedDataObjects())
{
    if (encryptedData != null)
    {
        myEncryptedData = encryptedData;
        break;
    }
}

Stream clearStream = myEncryptedData.GetDataStream(privateKey);
PgpObjectFactory clearFactory = new PgpObjectFactory(clearStream);

PgpObject message = clearFactory.NextPgpObject();
if (message is PgpCompressedData)
{
    message = ProcessCompressedMessage(message);
    PgpLiteralData literalData = (PgpLiteralData)message;
    using (Stream outputFile = File.Create(outputFilePath))
    {
        using (Stream literalDataStream = literalData.GetInputStream())
        {
            Streams.PipeAll(literalDataStream, outputFile);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception occurs on this line:

```
Stream clearStream = myEncryptedData.GetDataStream(privateKey);
```

I hope you can suggest something for me to try. I can provide any further details I might have missed.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code where you are using BouncyCastle?

Comment: I've updated to show the code. I've removed all the function calls, etc.

Comment: I'm having this same exact issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106918/bouncy-castle-pgp-decryption-issue

Comment: It would be lovely to have a [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @DaveBeta - have you figured out how to resolve this? I have the same issue, which I fixed temporarily by using newly generated keys. They worked for 2 weeks, and now the issue is back.

Comment: @GregS - I have the same issue, the only problem is that I haven't figured out how to reproduce it. So, we can't provide a real example as the data causing the issue is encrypted as it contains private data.